# hide column/td of the table by using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can we hide the column of the table by using jquery

```
< table >
  < tr >
   < td id="td_1" >name</ td >
   < td id="td_2" >title</ td >
   < td id="td_3" >desc</ td >
  </ tr >
  < tr >
   < td id="td_1" >Dave</ td >
   < td id="td_2" >WEB DEV</ td >
   < td id="td_3" >Blah Blah</ td >
  < /tr >
  < tr >
   < td id="td_1" >Nick< /td >
   < td id="td_2" >SEO< /td >
   < td id="td_3" >Blah Blah and blah< /td >
  < /tr >
< /table >
```

So suppose if someone want to hide first column i.e. td_1 from all rows, then what will be the code ?

Thanks in Advance
Dave

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/  ... don't even need the id fanciness... $('tr td:nth-child(n)') where n is the column number.

Comment: Also, please accept an answer if we helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#td_1").hide();
});
```

But ideally, you want to use a class instead of an ID.

so

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="td_1">name</td>
   <td class="td_2">title</td>
   <td class="td_3">desc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="td_1">Dave</td>
   <td class="td_2">WEB DEV</td>
   <td class="td_3">Blah Blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="td_1">Nick</td>
   <td class="td_2">SEO</td>
   <td class="td_3">Blah Blah and blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then you would use similar code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".td_1").hide()
});
```

So the only thing that changed is the hash(#) to a dot(.). Hash is for ID's, Dot is for classes.

**Yet another way would be to use the [nthChild](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr td:nth-child(1)').hide();
});
```

Where 1 is the column number to be hidden.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the gr8 idea, I'll use it some where else. But I forgot to mention that Those columns are dynamic, and their id gets increment . so how can I apply the css dynamically ? . 


Thanks

Comment: jquery has great support for css selectors.  You can write a selector like $('tr td:nth-child(1)') to select columns... http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I was going to mention that but you beat me to it :) +1

Comment: those jquery guys are geniuses!

Comment: John Resig is the Einstein of Javascript

Comment: Thank you all , I got the idea how to use nth child :) that'll solve my problem

Comment: pls check the syntax of document.ready() i think you miss a bracket at last

Comment: what if you had multiple tables?   $('tr td:nth-child(1)').hide();    Can you add a table id to the beginning of this like   $('#MytableID' 'tr td:nth-child(1)').hide();     syntax fix needed

Answer (score 1):

Some case, user use `th` for table header, you can use this script for hide column with `th`.

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('th:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(2)').hide();
})
```

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('th:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(2)').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
   <th id="td_1">name</th>
   <th id="td_2">title</th>
   <th id="td_3">desc</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="td_1">Dave</td>
   <td id="td_2">WEB DEV</td>
   <td id="td_3">Blah Blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="td_1">Nick</td>
   <td id="td_2">SEO</td>
   <td id="td_3">Blah Blah and blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id='test'>Hide title</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/hide-table-column-with-single-line-of.html