# Hide HTML Table Columns

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table that contains items and days.  The idea is that the first column of the item will be the daily usage of the item, the second column will be the incomming shipments of that item, and the 3rd column will be the daily inventory of that item.  My goal is to hide the first 2 columns automatically and then make them viewable again through a jquery mouseover.  My thought was to add a class to each row and have the first 2 rows set to hidden, on the jquery mouseover I would then .removeClass so that when the item row is highlighted all 3 rows are shown.

My question is: I have tried using CSS display:none; but doesnt seem to work for html table td elements?  Is there any other CSS command I could use or must I go about this a different way?

Heres an example of a table im trying to work with.

```css
table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
       
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100017</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100018</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100019</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100020</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>chips</u></th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>butterfingers</u></th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Flat Pretzels</u></th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Milk Chocolate</u></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to hide? `display:none` works just fine on `<td>` elements.

Comment: I believe he means the value of `colspan` doesn't change with the hidden `<td>`. It should be changed from `3` to `1` when two `td`s are hidden.

Comment: I would be hiding the first 2 columns under each item. And yes the col span would also be removed.  I added a class to the tds but when I use display:hidden; in the css file for those classes, it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide column/td of the table by using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296495/hide-column-td-of-the-table-by-using-jquery)

Comment: Roger, that is not what I ment at all.  On the snippet example columns 2 and 3, 5 and 6, 8 and 9 are what I'd like to start off as hidden

Answer (score 2):

You can hide children using something like this. Give the main table an #ID.
This represents 2 to be hidden

```
#tableID td:nth-child(-n+2) {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a sample for you. In this case changed the text color.. but for your case I would use visibility: hidden opposed to display:none as that will keep the cell spacing intact.

You can see I have it commented out where it should be used.

```js
 $("td:nth-child(4)").hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-child(-n+3)").addClass("fook");
 }, function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-child(-n+3)").removeClass("fook");
 });
 
  $("td:nth-child(7)").hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-child(5n),td:nth-child(7n-1)").addClass("fook");
 }, function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-child(5n),td:nth-child(7n-1)").removeClass("fook");
 });
 
   $("td:nth-child(10)").hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-child(8n),td:nth-child(10n-1)").addClass("fook");
 }, function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-child(8n),td:nth-child(10n-1)").removeClass("fook");
 });
 
  $("td:nth-child(13)").hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-last-child(-n+3)").addClass("fook");
 }, function() {
   $(this).siblings("td:nth-last-child(-n+3)").removeClass("fook");
 });
```

```css
* {
  text-align: center
}
td:nth-child(3n+0),td:nth-child(3n-1){
  background: pink;
  color: pink;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
}
td:nth-child(3n+1){
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black !important;
}
.fook {
  color: yellow !important;
  /* visibility: visible !important; */
}
#mytable {
  width: 100%
}
#mytable th:nth-child(-n+1) {
  background: lightgray;
}
#mytable th:nth-child(+1n+2) {
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100017</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100018</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100019</th>
    <th colspan='3'>100020</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>chips</u></th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>butterfingers</u></th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Flat Pretzels</u></th>
    <th colspan='3'><u>Milk Chocolate</u></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="first">
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="second">
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="first">
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fourth">
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fifth">
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
    <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer interests me!  I am still working on understanding using nth-child.  Since there are many different rows being hidden, and I only want to unhide 2 certain rows at a time depending on a mousover event, could I use nth-child with a jquery $(this) to unhide the 2 rows hidden right before the row that is being moused over? FYI there is no limit on the amount of rows that may be there in total, the only pattern is that there are 2 hidden rows, then 1 unhidden row.  The hidden rows should appear when the unhidden row is mouseover.  This pattern repeats infinitely

Comment: @Brandon did you ever get this going? I can help create the actual table you have.. let me know, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In this sample, this td class are hidden

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            .dailyusagetable, .incommingtable {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item #</th>
                <th colspan='3'>100017</th>
                <th colspan='3'>100018</th>
                <th colspan='3'>100019</th>
                <th colspan='3'>100020</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Component</th>
                <th colspan='3'><u>chips</u></th>
                <th colspan='3'><u>butterfingers</u></th>
                <th colspan='3'><u>Flat Pretzels</u></th>
                <th colspan='3'><u>Milk Chocolate</u></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2016-01-03</th>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2016-01-04</th>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2016-01-05</th>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2016-01-06</th>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2016-01-07</th>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td class='dailyusagetable'>0</td>
                <td class='incommingtable'>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
        </table>  

    </body>


</html>
```

Review your code

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your table to be hidden, but keep your spacing where it would have been, then use:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

Otherwise,

```
display:none;
```

is the way to go.

Comment: `display: hidden;` Really?

Comment: Sorry, it was visibility: hidden;